# Prevent indentation in command or environment after section header

Tags: macros, sectioning, line-breaking, indentation, vertical

I am creating a custom command with `\newcommand` that creates a new block of text on a new line. I want the command to behave as regular text with respect to indentation, i.e.:

1. be indented after a paragraph skip (i.e. when the user leaves a blank line).
2. not be indented after a newline (i.e., when the user types `\\` or simply does not leaves a blank line).
3. not be indented right after sections.

I accomplished the first two points by checking whether vertical mode is active.

However, the content in the command will be indented also if it is placed after a section header, which is not how regular paragraphs behave.
I tried using `if\@nobreak` to recognize if the current position is just below a header, but this does not work when `\if\@nobreak` is placed in \newcommand or in \newenvironment.

How can I avoid indentation after a section? Thank you in advance.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\testOne}[1]{%
  \ifhmode \def\isHMode{1}
  \else \def\isHMode{0} \fi
  \par%
  \ifnum\isHMode=1\noindent\fi
  #1%
}

\newcommand{\testTwo}{%
  \makeatletter 
  \if@nobreak nobreak found.
  \else nobreak NOT found.\fi
  \makeatother 
}


\begin{document}

AAA
\testOne{BBB non indented}

CCC

\testOne{DDD indented.}

\section{Section 1}
\makeatletter 
\if@nobreak nobreak found.
\else nobreak NOT found.\fi
\makeatother 

\section{Section 2}
\testTwo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the \makeatletter/\makeatother must be *outside* of your definition. But why do you need the test at all? If your command switch to hmode the indentation will be correct without such a test anyway, won't it?

Comment: ah, you want a \par before. Try `\newcommand{\testOne}[1]{\ifhmode\par\noindent\fi #1}`. But test also what happens after lists (in case your command is used there).

Comment: Not sure, but `\par#1` seems exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you everybody, what you suggested does work in 1) creating a new paragraph and 2) not indenting text after a section. 
I realize now I was unclear with the question. I would like that the command creates a new paragraph only if the user requires so, typically by leaving a blank line. This is why I used the check on the vertical mode. 
I will clarify the question.

Comment: What egreg suggested is right. The example I made initially is solved with \par#1 alone. However, the thing I am working on also involves a minipage, so I need the \if@nobreak to work, so that I can pass the information inside the minipage.
Anyway it turned out that placing the \makeatletter and \makeatother outside the command solved the problem. So, thank you @Ulrike Fisher! If you want to make an answer, I'll select it as the right one. If you don't mind, explaining why \makeatletter and \makeatother must go outside the command might be useful for other people stumbling here. Thank you.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer please see previous message